# WebApi routing dependency using ASP.Net visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package, maproute

I'm creating a WepApi on visual studio 2010, I've use NuGet for the api. Now when I'm registering the API in the Global File im getting the following error. The code below is found in the application_Start of the api.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

The following error is being given on `$RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute` - Instance argument:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' to 'System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection'
```

Any suggestions why this error is given?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute
```

instead of

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute
```

Comment: The GlobalConfiguration is not found in the Global file

Comment: GlobalConfiguration is part of the System.Web.Http namespace. You should have a reference to this in your Global.asax file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it applies to VS 2010, but add following ref in global

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.WebHost;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

Comment: What does DoNo mean? Do you mean "don't know"?

Comment: Then please edit your question to say that. Please use English on StackOverflow, not meaningless abbreviations.